# todonotes' \listoftodos with multi-paragraph \todo{}s

Tags: paragraphs, todonotes

There seems to be an issue with `todonotes`. I've been using `\todo{}`s that span multiple paragraphs for some time and never noticed any problems. Now I've tried to add a `\listoftodos` to my document - and failed. Here is a MWE that demonstrates the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\listoftodos

\section*{Whatever}
Some text\todo{Do this.}

\todo[inline]{Do that.}

A litle more text.

\todo[inline]{%
Oh, and by the way:

Remember the milk.}

\end{document}
```

The second compilation run fails with

```
Runaway argument?
{Oh, and by the way: 
! Paragraph ended before \@dottedtocline was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.3 \contentsline {todo}{Oh, and by the way: \par
                                                  Remember the milk.}{1}
```

Is there some kind of magic that I could apply to `todonotes` or do I have to reformat all of my todo notes?

Comment: This line generates a \par --Oh, and by the way: ... Remember the milk. Simply remove the double enter will solve the problem.

Comment: As mentioned above, he is using multiple paragraphs into his todo-notes. The double enter here is just simulating that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would it be OK for you, to add one more option to every note? I think it makes sense, not to print a whole chapter in the Todo List so something like `\caption[short for LoF]{long for display}` would be a good solution.

Therefore you should use the `caption={...}` option.

For your MWE this would look like:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\listoftodos    
\section*{Whatever}
Some text\todo{Do this.}

\todo[inline]{Do that.}

A litle more text.

\todo[inline, caption={short for LoTds}]{%
Oh, and by the way:

Remember the milk.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to automate this - like, having `\todo` only consider stuff before the first `\par`?

Comment: As the author of the todonotes package I know it quite well. But I'm not aware of a method for automating this. If a decent method exists let me know and it might be added to the package.